# If $P\cap B$ is maximal in $B$, then $P$ is maximal in $B[y]$

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains

As part of a much larger proof, I have encountered the following situation. I have that $B$ is a PID and $P$ is a prime ideal of the polynomial ring $B[y]$. I know that the intersection of $P$ and $B$ is non-empty, and therefore $P\cap B$ must be a maximal ideal of $B$ (because it is a prime ideal and every non-zero prime ideal of a PID maximal).

Now, I want to prove that $P$ is also a maximal element of $B[y]$. This is where I get stuck. I have tried several things like proving that $B[y]/P$ is a field or using the correspondence between the ideals of $B[y]$ that contain $P$ and the ideals of $B[y]/P$, but none of them got me anywhere. Could someone help me with this?

**Edit** I forgot to mention that we also know that $P$ is not a principal ideal.

Comment: Is this true? $(3)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[y]$, and its intersection with $\mathbb Z$ is nonzero (and thus maximal), but it is certainly not a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[y]$. Perhaps there are some additional conditions that you can add in the context of your proof to help prevent this sort of scenario?

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi oops! Edited my post to add an additional condition I forgot to mention. Thanks!

Comment: Ah—in that case, perhaps take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41196/on-prime-ideals-in-a-polynomial-ring-over-a-pid-from-reids-commutative-algebr